# How to generate Report Dashboard in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, performance

Jmeter has come up with a latest release `3.0`.
This is a major release not just bug fixes after almost a decade.
I read that we can generate `Report Dashboard` as well with the latest release.

Tell me how to do it?

Step by step detailed instructions would be great.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you already have a .jtl result file you can do it like:

```
jmeter -g /path/to/jtl/file -o /where/you/want/to/store/dashboard
```

If you would like the dashboard to be generated after the test run, you can [run JMeter in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) like:

```
jmeter -n -t /path/to/testplan -l /path/to/result.jtl -e -o /path/to/dashboard/folder
```

See [Full list of command-line options](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) for all possible JMeter command-line arguments listed and explained.

If above steps don't work - add the next lines to *user.properties* file (lives under "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.bytes=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.label=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.latency=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_code=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_message=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.successful=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_name=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.time=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format=ms
jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format=yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss
```

JMeter restart will be required in order to pick the properties up.

For dashboard customisation and tuning refer [Generating Report Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) user manual entry.

Comment: Okay so this is for the Non-GUI mode. If we want to get the dashboard at the end of my test in the GUI mode, who can we do that?

Comment: @Dmitri T When I try the above approach I get the following error "jmeter.JMeter: An error occurred:  java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError"

Comment: I added the lines in user.properties, but when I run the command `./jmeter -n -t /opt/Jmeter/PerformanceTesting/Fastmarketing_100TPS_LoadTest.jmx -l /opt/Jmeter/Results/SmokeTest.jtl -e -o /opt/Jmeter/Results/` I get the error
`Error: Unknown option -e` - any thoughts?

Comment: Dmitri I'm pinging you here so you can read Siraj's comment because I don't know if my conversion-to-comment pings you or not :-)

Comment: `jmeter -v`. If version is less than 3.0 - you won't get any dashboard

Comment: @Dmitri When I'm using `jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv` and `jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format = yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss` getting : Performance: Failed to parse file 'E:\Jenkins\jobs\JMeter-Loaded\builds\88\performance-reports\JMeterCSV\20160913-CreateDeleteGetOrder.jtl': For input string: "2016/09/13 15:16:40" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2016/09/13 15:16:40" at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source) at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Unknown Source) at java.lang.Long.valueOf(Unknown Source) at hudson.plugins.performance.JMeterCsvParser.ge

Comment: @Irina when you're using `jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv` and `jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format = yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss` , I noticed you save the file in **.jtl**. The Performance plugin can't process it because the timestamp is supported only in .csv. Therefore, you receive the error. You can change the filename to 20160913-CreateDeleteGetOrder.**csv** This fixed the error in my TestPlan.

Answer (score 0):

I have given brief in details how to generate report dashboard in Jmeter in this StackExchange question,please read it and you will generate HTML reports clearly for your test plan.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38263768/how-do-i-generate-a-dashboard-report-in-jmeter/39998477#39998477